# Maximo 7.5 birt reports not working in Maximo 7.6 birt

Tags: report, birt, maximo

We have recently upgraded our Maximo from 7.5 to 7.6. On 7.5 we had a lot of birt reports scheduled but those birt reports are not compatible with 7.6.
In 7.5 we use to directly point to the db2 database url in the report data source and execute the report. But in 7.6 we have to make a maximodatasource and rewrite the reports to use the maximodatasource.

Is there a way to run old 7.5 maximo reports with new maximo and birt as re-writing all reports would be a very time taking thing.

New Birt version : 4.7